# How to check the path on Android

Tags: c#, android, xml, path, unity-game-engine

I try to access to some XML file on my Android application created by unity. I put them in my StreamingAssets folder and recovering them by Application.streamingAssetsPath.

This is my code for getting the path:

```
 int index=0;
 index=m_RuleBaseFilePath.LastIndexOf("/");
 string path= m_RuleBaseFilePath.Substring(index,m_RuleBaseFilePath.Length-index);
 TextAsset textAsset = (TextAsset)Resources.Load(path, typeof(TextAsset));
 string realpath=Application.streamingAssetsPath+path;
```

This code works in the editor and for windows but not for Android when i try to build and run. I ask myself if i get the good path with this method.
Is there any debugging method for check that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: what you want to access?
Have you saved that XML files in Layout folder?

Comment: I try to access to my XML File with the path:
string realpath=Application.streamingAssetsPath+path;
Unity save the Xml files in the assets folder : test.apk\assets

Comment: check this may be help you. http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/516735/load-text-file-on-streaming-assets-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Make a [Coroutine](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) for the reading and use `WWW`.

```
void Start()
{
     WWW data = new WWW(Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/" + fileName);
     StartCoroutine(MyRead(data));
}

IEnumerator MyRead(WWW data) 
{
    yield return data;

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.error))
       myData = data.text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i've try on the unity editor. I try with this : WWW data = new WWW("file:///"+Application.streamingAssetsPath +"/"+path);
For recover the file in the editor first, but i always got :
You are trying to load data from a www stream which had the following error when downloading.
Couldn't open file /C:/Users/sébastien/Documents/New Unity Project 1/Assets/StreamingAssets/ExampleRulesBase.xml

Comment: Why are you putting `"file:///"+Application...+path);`? That's different than what I suggested.

Comment: But if you don't had that, you obtain could not resolve Host C:
So for resolve that, i've follow the indication of the unity documentation:
Note:'' When using file protocol on Windows and Windows Store Apps for accessing local files, you have to specify file:///__ (with three slashes).

Comment: Right windows. Try it out on Android to see what happens. That's how I tested it.

Comment: When i try to build the project for android (file->build), i have the same message, Application.streamingasssets return the path of the computer i guess.

Answer (score 0):

I edit the post for giving some news of my problem, I checked if the file are in my apk. I have my Xml files in the resources and the streamingassets for the moments, so i find them in my APK/assets and apk\assets\bin\Data. I've changed how i retrieve my files (It work on the editor but i get null object on android)

```
TextAsset read=(TextAsset)Resources.Load("ExampleRulesBase",typeof(TextAsset));
Debug.Log(read.text);
Stream s=GenerateStreamFromString (read.text);
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(s); 

public Stream GenerateStreamFromString(string s)
        {
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
            writer.Write(s);
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;
            return stream;
        }
```

I just need an XMLreader for continue but my log return me blank.

Answer (score 0):

android:

Application.dataPath    /data/app/xxx.xxx.xxx.apk

Application.streamingAssetsPath jar:file:///data/app/xxx.xxx.xxx.apk/!/assets

Application.persistentDataPath  /data/data/xxx.xxx.xxx/files

Application.temporaryCachePath  /data/data/xxx.xxx.xxx/cache

IOS:

Application.dataPath    Application/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxx.app/Data

Application.streamingAssetsPath Application/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/xxx.app/Data/Raw

Application.persistentDataPath  Application/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/Documents

Application.temporaryCachePath  Application/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx/Library/Caches

the path diff from platform.so please use Application.XXXX.

for youre case, u can read the xml from the path where u put them in editor.for example /Users/chenjd/workspace/chenjd/kiwi/xxx.xml
but use Application.streamingAssetsPath on Android.